# node.js event loop , the execution order of setTimeout and Promise.then is not stable

Tags: javascript, node.js, libuv

the code is:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('setTimeout1')
    Promise.resolve().then(function () {
        console.log('promise')
    });
})
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('setTimeout2');
});
```

I read the document of node.js and know about 6 phases of the event loop.
But I can't understand why the output of the code is unstable?
I think the output should be(environment: node.js 8.6.0)

```
setTimeout1
setTimeout2
promise
```

but the result is

```
setTimeout1
promise
setTimeout2
```

or

```
setTimeout1
setTimeout2
promise
```

Comment: something to do with "micro tasks" perhaps?

Comment: it may be worth noting, in firefox, the above code always (at least as far as I have tried) produces `setTimeout1, promise, setTimeout2`

Comment: thanks for comments @Jaromanda X . But the event loop model might be different between  node.js and browser. Sorry that I didn't mention the code is running in node 8.6.0 environment above the text.

Comment: I was just noting the difference. I too see the 95% `1,2,p` order with 5% `1,p,2` (in node 10.0.0) - to be honest, I was expecting the `1,p,2` order (since that's the order you get in Chrome browser as well - and isn't nodejs supposed to be using the Chrome js engine?)

Comment: @Mark_M  setTimeout() without the delay arg will be set to 1 by default. And it is different from process.nextTick(). [node event loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/)